# Group of Proper Symmetries of Painted Cube

Tags: abstract-algebra, group-theory, symmetric-groups

What is the proper symmetry group of a cube in which three faces, coming together at one vertex, are painted green and the other faces are red?

I know that the axis of rotation for which the rotations of $0$, $2\pi/3$, and $4\pi/3$ produce a proper rotational group is $x=y=z$ with the intersection points being the intersection of the similarly painted faces. But I'm not sure how to formulate this into a proper symmetry group. Any help would be great, thank you in advance!

Comment: "proper symmetry group" means reflections are excluded?

Comment: I think you want the dihedral group of the triangle.

Comment: Yes, @ParclyTaxel.

Comment: "Proper" has already many meanings, not to be used for another one. "Orientation-preserving", "direct", "group of motions" etc already mean what you want.